# Find user having continuously three year of attendenance

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, gaps-and-islands

I have a event table in which the list of user participated will be stored.

**Sample Data:**

```
╔════╦══════╦══════╗
║ id ║ name ║ year ║
╠════╬══════╬══════╣
║  1 ║ Arun ║ 2001 ║
║  2 ║ Arun ║ 2002 ║
║  3 ║ Arun ║ 2003 ║
║  4 ║ Arun ║ 2004 ║
║  5 ║ Arun ║ 2009 ║
║  6 ║ Arun ║ 2010 ║
║  7 ║ Arun ║ 2011 ║
║  8 ║ Bala ║ 2014 ║
║  9 ║ Bala ║ 2015 ║
║ 10 ║ Bala ║ 2017 ║
║ 11 ║ chan ║ 2014 ║
║ 12 ║ chan ║ 2015 ║
║ 13 ║ chan ║ 2018 ║
╚════╩══════╩══════╝
```

I need to find only the user who have attended continuously for three years with the years in new column. Even if the user attended for continuous 6 years then have to split into first three in an column and next three in another column.

**Output:**

```
╔════╦══════╦═══════════╗
║ id ║ name ║   years   ║
╠════╬══════╬═══════════╣
║  1 ║ Arun ║ 2001-2003 ║
║  2 ║ Arun ║ 2009-2011 ║
╚════╩══════╩═══════════╝
```

Comment: Search on gaps and islands

Comment: @Frisbee sample's will me much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

One way to get this information using the difference between `year` and an increasing sequence generated by `row_number()`:

```
select name, min(year), max(year)
from (select e.*,
             (year - row_number() over (partition by name order by year)
             ) as grp
      from events e
     ) e
group by name, grp
having count(*) >= 3;
```

This will find sequences of arbitrary length.  If you really only care about 3 years, then you can also use joins:

```
select e.name, e.year as FirstYearOfAtLeastThree
from events e
where exists (select 1 from events e2 where e2.name = e.name and e2.year = e.year + 1) and
      exists (select 1 from events e2 where e2.name = e.name and e2.year = e.year + 2) ;
```

Both of these can take advantage of an index on `events(name, year)`.  The second might be a bit faster than the first method.

Comment: i have update my question, could you please modify accordingly ?

Comment: @Ragul . . . Either answer is still appropriate.  Perhaps you want `= 3` for the condition in the first one.  The only difference is that the years are in two different columns, but concatenating them together -- if that is what you need -- is not particularly hard.

Comment: Exactly it is what i need that's why i am hear , I need to concatenating with every 3 years and join them using union clause.
sample's will me much appreciated.

Comment: you can add another `row_number() over( partition by grp order by year)` and divide it by 3 and use it as an additional group for your query.